# Is it true that "All spicy food is from Latin America"?

Tags: food

Nancy Qian, economist who has studied the Columbian Exchange [(2018)](https://www.washingtonpost.com/history/2018/10/08/christopher-columbus-potato-that-changed-world/):

> There really was no spicy food in the world before the Columbian Exchange.

Denver Nicks, author of *Hot Sauce Nation* [(2016)](https://www.forbes.com/sites/megykarydes/2016/09/29/the-heat-behind-americas-favorite-condiment-hot-sauce/):

> Before the Columbian Exchange, there were no chilies outside of the Americas. Which is to say, when Christopher Columbus set sail for India in 1492, Indian food wasn’t spicy. Thai food wasn’t spicy (in the sense of “spicy’ as in the heat-pain that chilies impart). There was no spicy Chinese food.

Highly-upvoted comment at Cooking.SE [(2018)](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/93840/):

> More interestingly, chillis are also new world crops. Therefore all those hot, spicy, Thai, Indian, Malay and Filipino foods are actually modern - invented after the Portuguese or Dutch introduced chilli peppers to Asian cultures

*Crash Course* [(2012)](https://nerdfighteria.info/v/HQPA5oNpfM4/):

> until 500 years ago ...  Indians lived without curry, which contains chilies, a New World food

*The Awl* [(2017)](https://www.theawl.com/2017/06/all-spicy-food-is-from-latin-america/):

> All Spicy Food Is From Latin America.

---

To what extent is the above claim true?

To me, it seems "obvious" that spicy food has a much longer history in Asia than just to 1500 and that the chili plant isn't the only way to achieve a spicy flavor. I also easily found the following examples:

- The Japanese **wasabi** - according to [this page](https://wasabi.org/articles/the-past-present-and-future-of-wasabi-japanese-horseradish/), "The first Japanese medical encyclopaedia called 'Honzo-wamyo'” was published in A.D. 918 and it states that “wild ginger” (*Wasabia japonica*) had been grown in Japan for at least a thousand years"
- One [journal article](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2352618114000043) claims that the Korean chili pepper **gochu** has been cultivated for at least 1,500 years. However, this journal article has been criticized by several commenters below (now moved to chat) and was also recently thoroughly debunked by [wotan_weevil at Reddit - Ask Historians](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/9m2vxd/korean_food_is_notoriously_spicy_which_is_a_bit/e7f0d9b/) (I found this only a number of days after first posting this question).
- The **[Szechuan/Sichuan pepper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sichuan_pepper)** was already mentioned in ancient Chinese poetry (詩經, 11th-7th centuries BC) -- English translation [here](https://e-info.org.tw/node/40953)

But perhaps wasabi, gochu, and the Szechuan pepper were rare examples and for the most part the claim of this question's title is true.

---

Several have correctly pointed out that the word *spicy* is unfortunately quite ambiguous in English. For example, cinnamon and nutmeg are spices, but are not what I mean by *spicy* in the current context. In other languages there are words for what I am thinking of in much more unambiguous terms --- *picante* in Spanish, 辣 in Chinese, or *pedas* in Malay.

Perhaps there is a more scientific term for this that someone knows of. (I am aware that there is something called the [Scoville scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scoville_scale), but this seems to measure only capsaicins which seem to be present only in chili.)

---

I have also found the following fruitful discussions on other sites:

From Reddit - Ask Historians:

- ["What was Indian food like before contact with the New World?"](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/4rwri1/what_was_indian_food_like_before_contact_with_the/)
- ["What was Asian cuisine like before the Colombian exchange?"](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/1h7g04/what_was_asian_cuisine_like_before_the_colombian/)
- [What did "Old World" cuisines that are today known for their spicy foods taste like before peppers were imported from the Americas?](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/5osb44/what_did_old_world_cuisines_that_are_today_known/)
- [What is the history of curry? Who invented it? How did it spread? Is it really a British thing and not Indian?](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/24icha/what_is_the_history_of_curry_who_invented_it_how/)
- [Hot peppers originally came from the Americas, but India, Thailand, and large parts of China are famous for their spicy foods. How did they arrive, and how long was it before they became an integral part of the cuisine?](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/5zao2v/hot_peppers_originally_came_from_the_americas_but/)

From Quora:

- ["What was Indian cuisine all about before potatoes, chilies, and tomatoes were brought to India?"](https://www.quora.com/What-was-Indian-cuisine-all-about-before-potatoes-chilies-and-tomatoes-were-brought-to-India)

The top answer at this last discussion quotes [Achaya (2000)](https://www.cse.iitk.ac.in/users/amit/books/achaya-2000-story-of-our.html):

> We had a glimpse in the last chapter that chillis are not really Indian. These
>   wonderful materials were brought to India from Mexico, perhaps in the late 16th
>   century. They took a little while to catch on, but in about a hundred years, the
>   use of chillis spread to every part of India. Before that, it was pepper that was
>   used to give the pungency that is so characteristic of Indian food. In one of the sections of the ***Ain-i-Akbari***, written in 1590, there is a list of 50 dishes cooked in Akbar's court: all of them use only pepper to impart spiciness. In most Indian languages, the name for the chilli is simply a variation of the earlier name for pepper in the same language. For example, in Hindi, we say ***kalimirch*** (black pepper) for pepper and harimirch (green pepper) for chilli. In Tamil, the word for pepper is *milagu* and that for chilli is *milagai* (= milagu-kai (pepper+fruit)). In Kannada, the words are *karimenasu* and *menasinkayi*. Try this exercise in your own language.
>
> It is not difficult to understand why the chilli so quickly replaced pepper in our cooking. While the pepper vine grows almost only in Kerala, chillis can be grown in almost every backyard, or cultivated in fields, all over the country. Thus, they were easily avaliable everywhere at a low price. All the many varieties that we know come to us from Mexico and none of them was developed afterwards in India. These include the green chilli, red chilli, long red chilli, very small and very hot green bird chilli, and the large mild capsicum. To make chillipowder, the long bright-red variety with thin skins can be dried in the sun, and ground either with its seeds to give more pungency, or without it to give a milder chilli-powder. In fact, it is no exaggeration to say that the humble chilli from Mexico really revolutionized the food of India.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85790/discussion-on-question-by-kenny-lj-is-it-true-that-all-spicy-food-is-from-latin).

Comment: An English cookbook, [The Forme of Cury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Forme_of_Cury), was published in the 1390s, and all hot food was called "cury" from the French word cuire, meaning to cook.

Comment: @konradrudolph - the system flagged multiple comments in a short time period.  I moved them to chat as is the normal procedure.

Comment: Moving the comments to chat is not a statement about the validity of the comments.  It is an indication that discussion is occurring in comments.

Comment: @SpiceE.Guy: *all hot food was called "cury"* --- do you have any source for that? My understanding is that the present English *curry* is from the Tamil *kari*.

Comment: While it's not used in food, the resiniferatoxin contained in the resin spurge (a plant from in North Africa) puts anything capsaicin-based to shame, at 16 billion (yes, with a b) Scoville units.

Comment: Seems like this questions is to a large extent prompting discussions of nomenclature rather than history. Perhaps the question should be edited to be more clearly a historical question, such as "Is it true that the Old World lacked plants of the genus Capsicum prior to Columbus' voyages?"

Comment: @Acccumulation: We already know that the answer to that particular question is "yes". It would be as if I asked if people in the Old World ate nutty foods before Columbus and you then restricted attention to solely the peanut.

Comment: Yes, the English language isn't adequate for describing what billions of people around the world know and taste everyday. And yes, scientists (based mostly in countries that traditionally eat zero spicy foods) have not adequately studied this matter and are perhaps unable to clearly define what constitutes spiciness. However, I believe this question remains perfectly meaningful.

Comment: @KennyLJ There is a sense in which "spicy" means "capsicum". There isn't a sense in which "nutty" means specifically "peanut". If we take the question to be whether there are any Old World spices, then the answer is quite trivially "yes". At least "were there capsicum" is not completely trivial. In your analogy, if someone were asking about such a vague term as "nutty", I would support a VTC.The primary focus of the answers has been linguistics, botany, and taxonomy, not history. And in what country do people eat zero spicy foods?

Comment: @Kenny LJ: The problem is that current American (if not English as a whole) has so misused the word "spicy" to describe the effect of capsicum-containing plants that it's not possible to even ask the question without at least a page or two explaining just what is meant by "spicy".  Having grown up in a subculture in which chili peppers were basically unused (maybe a little paprika, but just a touch), I still think of "spicy" as being the flavors of cardamom, cinnamon, cloves, ginger, nutmeg...  All of which of course existed in the Old World long before Columbus.

Comment: Chili has been spread as a substitute to (much more expensive) pepper in Eastern Europe / Balkan, too. Would you call chilli an entire new spiciness if t is a cheap substitute in hot food?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

**While it is true that most hot spices originated in the Americas, spicy food was evident in most ancient civilizations and originated from many different regions of the world.**

There is both physical and literary evidence for the use spices and spicy food dating back to antiquity in Asia and Europe, as well as the Americas. The *[Cambridge World History of Food, vol. 1](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/The_Cambridge_World_History_of_Food.html?id=RSSkDNzKQacC&redir_esc=y)* lists numerous examples, among which are **Grains of Paradise**, a hot spice related to cardamom (date uncertain, origin: West Africa), **Ginger** (2nd millennium BC, origin: SE Asia), and **Pepper** (origin: prehistoric India). Then there is also **Long Pepper**, a hotter version of pepper (prehistoric, origin: India) and [**Cubeb**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piper_cubeba) (or Java pepper) originating in Java and Sumatra. In short,

> All of the well-known ancient civilizations used a complement of
>   typical spices.

[image] (click for fullsize)

ABOVE *Grains of Paradise came to Europe from West Africa in medieval times. Image source: [The Spice House](https://static.thespicehouse.com/images/file/481/large_square_Grains_of_Paradise__close.jpg)*

[image]

*Long Pepper, mentioned in [Ayurveda texts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayurveda) which may have originated in Indian prehistory. [Image attribution](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Piper_longum.jpg#metadata)*

There is literary evidence for the use of long pepper from India in ancient Greece, and the [Romans used spices](https://foodanddining.omeka.net/exhibits/show/spicesoftheancientromanworld/spices-in-roman-recipes) in most of the dishes found in [Apicius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apicius), a collection of recipes. Many of these spices came from India and pepper was

> the staple commodity of the Roman imperial trade with India

*Source: J. Wilkins, S. Hill, Food in the Ancient World, citing Miller (1969)*

Peppers from India were evident in [early medieval Europe](https://books.google.com.ph/books/about/Food_in_Medieval_Times.html?id=jtgud2P-EGwC&redir_esc=y), and saffron from Greece or the Near East was also used:

> If saffron was the most exclusive spice, pepper was the most common
>   in medieval Europe. It was consumed by the rich and those of more
>   modest means, albeit in smaller quantities.

Comment: I have also just come across this article ["Phytoliths in Pottery Reveal the Use of Spice in European Prehistoric Cuisine"](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0070583) (2013), which dates the use of garlic mustard in Europe to 6,100 to 5,750 BP.

Answer (score 89):

I live in Thailand, and I wondered about the same. I asked this question to several Thais with some knowledge in history. Chili peppers come from the Americas. That's correct. They are imported into Asia. Also correct.

But the **peppercorn** from the [black pepper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_pepper) is native to Asia. This was - and still is - in use before Europeans introduced Chili peppers to Asia. Black, white and green pepper come all from the same plant.

Comment: And is indeed the most used form of pepper in Europe as well.

Comment: Here's a thread from Seasoned Advice about the history of Indian cooking, which backs this up: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/65202/what-was-indian-food-like-before-the-arrival-of-the-chili-pepper-from-the-americ

Comment: I think it's important to recognize that biologically peppercorns like black pepper and chili/bell peppers are completely unrelated plant species in different families [Piperaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piperaceae) and [Solanaceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solanaceae) which aren't even in the same Order, and the compounds they produce that mediate their "spiciness" are completely different as well.

Comment: To add on to @BryanKrause’s comment, the different compounds also provide rather different forms of spiciness. Pepper has a sharp, but short-lived bite. Similar (in sensation, not biology or chemistry) stories for other Old World sources of spiciness, like horseradish, mustard, or wasabi. The lingering, building heat of chili peppers is, as far as I know, unique to those New World plants—but I would love to see more information on whether or not “as far as I know” is accurate.

Comment: That's not the question. It's not about the spiciness of the food, or what causes it. It is about America being the source of all spicy foods.

Comment: @BryanKrause: I think it is a peculiarity of the English language that this confusion even exists. For example, in German, "pepper" is called "Pfeffer" and "chili pepper" is called just "Chili". There just is no potential for confusion there, the word "Pfeffer" (pepper) is exclusively reserved for referring to peppercorns.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I agree, though it's more than just the word "pepper" because "hot" is also used in English to describe the flavors of both chili peppers and things like mustard/black pepper. In any case, it's pretty clear the reference the OP had was referring to chili peppers in making the claim that "spicy foods" are from the Americas, everything else here is just an argument about whether "spicy" means something besides "has capsaicin from chili peppers." :)

Comment: @BryanKrause German is a *bit* better with "hot".  Chillis and peppercorns from the freezer are both *scharf*, but plain rice that has just been boiled is *heiß*.

Comment: @JörgWMittag: in my experience at least, it's a peculiarity of only some (not all) English dialects. For example, in Australian English "pepper" refers exclusively to peppercorns, "bell peppers" are called "capsicums", and "chilli peppers" are referred to as "chillies".

Comment: @JörgWMittag: and, of course, Pfeffer in German also has the mostly outdated meaning of spice in general: noone would expect Pefferkuchen to contain lots of (or as the only or predominant spice) peppercorns.

Comment: @cbeleites And I think that most Americans are most familiar with "pfeffer" in "pfeffernusse".

Comment: Black pepper and chillies have differences in overall flavour, but the same kind of hotness (different to the mustard/horseradish/wasabi hotness). Different chemical, but the same hot effect on the mouth. If you put chillies in a cream sauce you'll see what I mean - it tastes like a peppercorn sauce.

Comment: @Mac: I believe you are correct. From the [Cambridge World History of Food](https://books.google.com/books?id=RSSkDNzKQacC&pg=PA283&dq=%22It+is+in+the+United%22): *It is in the United States that the greatest confusion exists. Both the Anglicized spelling, “chili” (chilies), and the Spanish chile (chiles) are used by some for the fruits of the Capsicum plant, but chili is also used as a short form of chili con carne, a variously concocted mixture of meat and chillies.* (The first time I was in the US I was confused that "chili" referred to a bowl of meat with nothing spicy in it.)

Comment: White pepper too was very often used (in large amounts) in Chinese cooking before the introduction of the chili.

Comment: @Kenny LJ: And to add even more confusion, in American "pepper" (or "bell pepper") is also the name of the large, non-hot capsicums used as a vegetable: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_pepper

Comment: Wow, so Thai and Chinese food wasn't necessarily "spicy" in the sense of capcaisin (however it's spelled), and only "gingery" and "peppery" until the europeans arrived? When did Thailand get the chillipepper??

Answer (score 48):

Mustard, horseradish, ginger and cumin all grow in the old world and are by most definitions spicy.

Comment: This answer could be improved by reference to the documentary record of the past (citation and quotation).

Comment: While they are "spicy" I don't know if this falls into the classification of what the OP is looking for. They are specifically looking for peppers and related foods that burn the mouth when consumed. None of the above really do that.

Comment: @ggiaquin16 horseradish do burn mouth when consumed. If you haven't noticed, you have never consumed real horseradish.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo: while I agree with your comment in general, the kind of "hotness" from horseradish is different from, say, jalapeños (it also goes into the nose / sinus). But I agree that ultimately it is a matter of semantics (or biochemical definitions of the molecules which cause the sensation)

Comment: @WoJ Radishes *definitely* go "into the nose". This whole question sounds a bit silly to me because where I'm from (Central Europe), peppers weren't really used for "spiciness" much. Pretty much all the "traditional" spicy dishes don't involve peppers at all, and the ones that involve peppers usually use rather sweet peppers, not chilli (there are exceptions, though). I think a big part of the problem is that people are familiar with their kinds of e.g. radishes that don't sting much. A lot of cultivation aimed to make things like onions and radishes sweeter.

Comment: @WoJ The kind of radishes we use to spice up foods really go into everything (and twice, if you know what I mean :P ). Your mouth hurts, your tongue hurts, your throat hurts, your nose hurts, your eyes tear up, even your esophagus hurts (and sometimes, the stomach as well). And it's much the same with the other mentioned spicy ingredients, like black pepper or mustard - just because you're used to them not really being spicy doesn't mean other cultivars (and different processing) aren't. It's different spicy than peppers, yes. But definitely not mild in any sense of the word.

Comment: @Luaan: I would be interested in the horseradish variety you mention -- I had the opportunity to eat horseradish in Poland (raw, and then with mashed eggs) and while the raw version was tough to the nose/sinus, it was only really a one-shot thing. The "hotness" vanished quickly and did not come back afterwards (I know what you mean :)). For me it was only the nose/sinus irritation which was visible, but then it may very well be an individual reaction.

Comment: @WoJ Ah, no, definitely - it doesn't last as long as peppers do. But that has all to do with solubility - capsaicin doesn't get washed away easily, and every time you splash it down with more water, it comes back. That's why "peppery" foods aren't quite as hot if they're fatty - the capsaicin on your e.g. tongue gets absorbed in the fat and washed down to your stomach. Try a really hot pepper, and then rinse the painful spot with butter - it will stop right away.

Comment: While a lot of different plants may be described as "hot" or "spicy", the idea that the "hotness" that comes from mustard or horseradish is essentially the same sensation as the "hotness" from a chile pepper, or even the "hotness" from a black peppercorn is immediately and obviously not true - at least in my mouth. I'm really not sure why "cumin" is considered spicy at all in this context, but everyone's palate is different.

Comment: As for sources, according to wikipedia, horseradish is mentioned in Greek mythology as well as in Roman sources, and was cultivates as well as found wild in Central Europe in the Middle Ages. I seem to remember that horseradish was *the* basis for spicy sauces in Germany till much later (when other spices were not only known/traded but also affordable). Also mustard was (still wikipedia) was cultivated in ancient Greece and Rome, (the biblical mustard seed seems to refer to another plant).

Comment: @WoJ: there's a wide range in how hot horseradish (and horseradish sauces) are. Importandly, if the root is not really fresh (or was stored inappropriately), it can loose all the hot stuff (it's volatile - that's why it goes into the nose as well).  Further, when preparing, you can decide whether you want to "help" it still further by combining with vinegar, or whether you're after a milder sauce (to be consumed in large quantities) by adding bread or for condiment cream. If you want to have the true head-spitting experience, volounteer to scrape the root (get a good fresh one)...

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo  "horseradish do burn mouth when consumed. If you haven't noticed, you have never consumed real horseradish." Or they have a biological response that differs from yours.

Comment: @ggiaquin16 Mustard can be very variable. Some is mild, like German or American, and some is eye-wateringly peppery such as English yellow mustard. The heat response is different to Chilli though and goes to the nose more than the mouth.

Answer (score 44):

#### Answer to question as originally posted:

This is more of a language use problem, in several ways.

The first comment is correct in stating that capsaicin containing dishes (these are the "hot, spicy") are very popular in Asia now. But in Asia it was impossible for those dishes to contain capsaicin [before Columbus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Columbian_Exchange). The whole genus Capsicum was simply absent from Asia before 1500. Many Asians are oblivious to the fact and [surprised](https://spicyquest.com/where-are-chili-peppers-from/) to learn that chili-pepper is not like black pepper originally native to Asia.

Even a few scientists seemed to have been surprised by that, at least sometimes, as is evidenced for example by the misleading taxonomic classification of a hot bonnet pepper, named [Capsicum chinense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsicum_chinense), that is not really "from China":

> Despite its name, C. chinense or "Chinese capsicum" is misleading. All Capsicum species originated in the New World. Nikolaus Joseph von Jacquin (1727–1817), a Dutch botanist, erroneously named the species in 1776, because he believed they originated in China due to their prevalence in Chinese cuisine after their introduction by European explorers.

The blog post uses even less precise language, as first of all those dishes in Asia alluded to originate from Asia. And more importantly second: it drops the signifier 'hot' and equates 'spicy' with 'capsaicin containing'. But that is a peculiarism of usage, ambiguous in itself and not universal to all variants of the English language, differing by regions.

From a sister site:

> [Difference between “spicy” and “hot”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50080/difference-between-spicy-and-hot) 
>   I make a distinction between "hot" and "spicy" food ("hot" not referring to temperature). I consider "hot" food the kind that "burns" and "spicy" food that has lots of flavor, but that may or may not "burn", but has some "heat" to it and is flavorful.
>
> I've been told that there is no real difference between the two and that I'm crazy for thinking that Tabasco sauce makes something "hot", while something like curry, ginger, or cumin makes something "spicy". Please help me out a little here with a little clarification.

Or as [Wikipedia put it:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pungency)

> The terms "pungent" and "pungency" are rarely used in colloquial speech but are preferred by scientists as they eliminate the potential ambiguity arising from use of the words "hot" and "spicy", which can also refer to temperature and the presence of [spices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spice), respectively.
>   For instance, a [pumpkin pie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumpkin_pie) can be both hot (out of the oven) and spicy (due to the common inclusion of spices such as [cinnamon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon), [nutmeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nutmeg), [allspice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allspice), [mace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mace_(spice)), and [cloves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clove)), but it is not pungent. (A food critic may nevertheless use the word "piquant" to describe such a pie, especially if it is exceptionally well-seasoned.) Conversely, pure capsaicin is pungent, yet it is not naturally accompanied by a hot temperature or spices.
>   As the [Oxford](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/piquancy?q=piquancy), [Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/piquancy?showCookiePolicy=true), and [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/piquant) dictionaries explain, the term "piquancy" refers to mild pungency and flavors and spices that are much less strong than [chilli peppers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chili_pepper), including, for example, the strong flavor of some tomatoes. In other words, pungency always refers to a very strong taste whereas piquancy refers to any spices and foods that are "agreeably stimulating to the palate", in other words to food that is spicy in the general sense of "well-spiced".

Going from that wikipage to corresponding entries illustrates that *this* [problem](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/red-hot-chilli-peppers-vs-chilli-vs-hot-chilli-vs-hot-pepper.1466106/) is largely absent from [other languages](https://ask.metafilter.com/269060/Hot-as-a-synonym-for-spicy), but there are [others](https://doi.org/10.1002/chemv.201400031) around the fruit.

The problem is entrenched and likely to persist.

> [It's a genuine inadequacy in English vocabulary](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/55057/257060), with no simple fix:
>
> "Hot" is ambiguous
>   "Spicy" is also ambiguous (certain kinds of cake, for example, are spicy but not hot)
>   "Piquant" is not frequently used, so could seem pretentious.

And to illustrate the regional variations, from a [recent chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/84394?m=47150835#47150835):

> ME: Do you use 'spicy' in that way? Is that not more like "hot". Re-checked a couple dictionaries and it is always just listing 'copious amounts of spices'.
>   TED: Yes, I do. Something with lots of Oregano in it is not "spicy".
>   ME: Then I am quite sure there is also one of these maps that picture this as a regionalism? Clearly something with *Piper nigrum* or *Zingiber officinale* is also spicy/hot. But indeed I find it very strange what is called *-pepper around the globe. WP describes capsaicin as pungent…

[Equally:](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/182485/257060)

> In English 'spicy/hot' doesn't always mean 'with chillies' as many people find even weak "French" mustard to be 'spicy/hot'.Mustard can be considered 'spicy' in England but standard English mustard is not spicy due to the addition of chillies, it is the mustard seeds themselves, they are Brassicas and do not contain capsaicin.
>
> Most spices are really just flavourings and do not contain capsaicin.
>   Asking for no chilli should still allow you to have a flavourful dish without the pain but some people may mistake no chilli for no spices but at least your food will be warmer than the ambient temperature and not contain chilli rather than at, or cooler than, the ambient temperature and not contain chilli.

So Asians used pepper and other spices well before Columbus. Then they were introduced to capsaicin containing plants and allspice. Asian dishes are from Asia and contained spices before the columbian exchange. Another exchange to observe is that the very word "spicy" changed its meaning by that and for some refers exclusively to chili-pepper dishes.

---

Oxford English Dictionary

> [hot:](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/88782?rskey=sdGCfh&result=2&isAdvanced=false#eid)
>   - Of food or drink: prepared by heating and served before cooling.
>   - Of a food, drink, spice, etc.: having a taste or smell characterized by a burning sensation; pungently spicy; acrid, biting. Also of a taste or smell (occasionally in figurative contexts).
>
> [spicy:](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/186546?redirectedFrom=spicy#eid)
>   - Having the characteristic qualities of spice; of the nature of spice.
>   - Flavoured or mixed with spice.

The most intriguing part about this is that in English the familiar *Piper nigrum* (black) pepper gave its name away to all these spicy-hot chili peppers and variant spellings and meanings, because of their similarity in tongue sensations. All while Columbus had set sail to find trade routes for the spices, now in some parts of the world only those dishes containing plants discovered after Columbus are called spicy? Quite a carrousel indeed.

---

#### Answer supplement to updated question

Now that it should be clear that spicy *should* logically mean containing lots of spices/herbs/aroma/taste/zing/hotness:

The claim is correct if spicy is equated with capsaicin, and the claim is correct if it is assumed that nearly all popular spicy Asian dishes with their recipes from today would be missing a crucial ingredient without Latin Americas gift to the culinary world.

However, we were nitpicking with language, let's be serious about the history of spicy food in Asia:

> Etymologists believe that “curry” originally came from kari, a word in Tamil that means sauce or gravy. The history of this preparation goes back more than 4,000 years to the Indus Valley civilization, where people often used stone mortar and pestle to finely grind spices such as fennel, mustard, cumin and others. In fact, excavations at Harappa and Mohenjodaro have unearthed pottery fragments with traces of turmeric and ginger, belonging to the period between 2600 – 2200 BC, thus making curry (or at least the predecessor to curry) one of the oldest food items in the world. As pointed out by historians, the curry was often eaten with rice, which was already being cultivated in the area.
>
> Sumerian tablets that have survived also talk of a similar food recipe for meat in some kind of spicy gravy and served with bread, as early as 1700 BC. The Apicius cookbook of the 4th century AD contains many meat recipes that were cooked in a similar fashion, with the use of ingredients like coriander, vinegar, mint, cumin and so on. Authored in the 1390s, The Forme of Cury is significant for possessing the earliest reference to the word “cury”, though it was taken from the French term “cuire” for cooking.  With the arrival of the Portuguese in Goa in the 15th century as well as the Mughals in India in the early 16th century, the curry recipe underwent multiple revisions.
>   <sub>[Realm of History: 9 Of The Oldest Food Recipes From History Still In Use Today](https://www.realmofhistory.com/2018/04/04/9-oldest-food-recipes-history/)</sub>

If we just put aside the dubious language definitions completely. And if we put aside the equally dubious chemical reductionist stance of the scoville scale that measures pungency just by casicin content. Then we can still trust our senses. Going by purely [organoleptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organoleptic) categories, it might become clear that even the isolated until 1788 Australians used plants like [pepperberry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptocarya_obovata), [mountain pepper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tasmannia_lanceolata) to spice up their food.

Example to add to the wikipedia entry:

> *Tasmannia lanceolata* is the tree that produces the Tas- manian pepperberry and leaf. Dr Konczak says ‘It is a very aromatic native pepper which was developed under the Antarctic climate’ when Australia was attached to Gondwanaland.

Or a spicy recipe devoid of American or Asian spice:

> 600 g kangaroo tenderloin
>   250 ml beef broth jus
>   6 quandongs
>   50 g riberries
>   50 g desert lime
>   4 rosella  owers
>   50 g muntries
>   2 tsp 7 spice
>   400 g warrigal greens
>   2 tsp butter
>   1 cup mixed beach herbs (salt bush, barilla, beach mustard, beach banana)
>   <sub>John Newton: "The Oldest Foods in the World. 
>   A history of Australian native foods with recipes", New South: Sydney, 2016.</sub>

Comment: This language focused response could be improved by reference to the entry of the concept of hot as in culinary spice into English. OED3 ought to have first (located) use with a quote.

Comment: _"capsaicin containing dishes (these are the "hot, spicy") are very popular in Asia now, impossible to contain it before Columbus."_ People lived there before Columbus you know

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I know. They were all over the place, those people. But the genus Capsicum was absent from Asia before 1500, or what do you read into what you quoted?

Comment: A bit of a side note but those piquant tomatoes are also originally New World crops. No Italian had a tomato pre-~1500AD.

Comment: @BryanKrause Tomatioes in India and China are also a typical delight. In fact they are everwhere now.

Comment: @LangLangC For sure, although I think much like chili peppers are such an integral part of Indian and SE Asian cuisine, tomatoes are pretty central to Mediterranean cooking. Though I am also invariably putting an American bias on world cuisine. Neither region had either until quite recently, historically speaking.

Comment: In short, this is simply a misuse of English.  The "hot, spicy" sensation caused by capsaicin is not hot in the temperature sense (and at least to me, is distinctly different), and is only one of a great many spices.

Comment: @Bryan Krause: Another example would be potatos in Ireland (and Northern Europe generally).  A common, perhaps distinctive, feature of the cuisine, but non-existant before Columbus.  Then there's the use of corn (maize) in African cooking...

Comment: @jamesqf That's an interesting personal observation, given that capsaicin activates exactly the same receptor, TRPV1, that provides the primary sensation of hot temperature (piperine from black pepper and similar also does, but it less specific). Good point of potato and corn as well. I think in general people don't appreciate just how much cooking worldwide was affected by new world crops.

Comment: @Bryan Krause: There must be secondary receptors, then.  Or perhaps it's due to the flavor of other things in the dishes.  Even different peppers have different flavors aside from their "hotness", e.g. cayenne vs paprika.  But perhaps a better question for the Biology or Cooking sites?

Comment: @jamesqf It acts directly on the receptor, which I suspect means that there's no proper counter-balance from e.g. the cold receptors - so it might feel "weird" compared to a "real" sensation. But definitely, peppers also have flavours, not just hotness. But then again, so does e.g. hot tea. The main difference is that hot tea actually causes damage, while capsaicin doesn't.

Comment: @Luaan: Except that one usually can feel the (physical) heat of a hot drink before putting it in one's mouth, something that's not true of capsaicin-containing food.

Comment: @jamesqf Yes, I imagine there's many tiny differences once you go deeper into the problem. Human perception is a lot about synthesising tons of varied sensory inputs (both external and internal), so I feel that both saying "It's the pure meaning of "hot", since it directly stimulates the heat receptors" and "It's very different, since in a real "hot" sensation, you have ten more things happening at the same time" are equally valid. From the evolution point of view, it's pretty clear too - for humans, receptors that distinguish "hot" from "chilli" weren't important; for peppers, great hack.

Comment: Surely oregano is an herb, not a spice, so copious amounts of oregano should never be considered "spicy" by anyone.

Comment: Since this answer was first posted, I have added the following to my question: "Several have correctly pointed out that the word spicy is unfortunately quite ambiguous in English. For example, cinnamon and nutmeg are spices, but are not what I mean by spicy in the current context. In other languages there are words for what I am thinking of in much more unambiguous terms --- *picante* in Spanish, 辣 in Chinese, or *pedas* in Malay." // I hope my question doesn't have to hinge too heavily on the inability of the English language to adequately describe a certain taste, flavor, or sensation.

Comment: @BryanKrause: LangLangC didn't have a "choice" with the tomato example due to quoting. But (at least the German version, pikant, which seems to correspond well to the definition for the English usage) would be used e.g. also for a cheese that has flavor as well as being slightly pungent. My guess is that the pungency in pikant food is too low to qualify for the question here. (But then I'm biased by the German usage of "scharf" [lit. sharp] for pungent food)

Comment: This is super interesting.  I never would have thought to use "spicy" to mean "spiced"/"seasoned", only for chili heat.

Answer (score 19):

*Spicy* and related words can definitely describe the sensations provoked by various food items. The words seem used most often to describe the substance [capsaicin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capsaicin), present in chile peppers. In that sense, assuming there are no capsaicin-bearing Old World plants, the claim is true. In the sense that peppercorns and so on are spicy too, it is false.

Answer (score 6):

Demonstrably false.

While it is true that the *Capsicum* genus (as in chili and the like) comes from Latin America, the *Piper* genus ("pepper" in its various forms) as well as ginger is native to Asia. Their use in Europe predates the Columbian Exchange by over a thousand years (pepper being rare, but known and available via the Silk Road) and *at least* 3,000 years (probably much more) in Asia. Ginger has a long history of being used for making spicy food *in lack of pepper* (which obviously means pepper must have been known).

I wouldn't be able to tell how long *exactly* pepper has been known, or available in Europe (but surely since at least the Tang dynasty since there's written records on trade with the Byzantine Empire), but Óc Eo provides evidence of trade with Rome even before the second century, so...

That aside, the mere name *Piper* is a dead giveaway since it's a Sanscrit word. Sanscrit has been spoken during the last 3,000-4,000 or so years in what region again... Latin America? Well, no. Look farther east.
The German translation of "go jump in the lake" which re-translates literally to to "go where the pepper grows" (= India) is a similar hint.

Answer (score 4):

I think people are correct when they mention the ambiguity of the term in English, but I think I know what you mean. In Spanish, the spicy sensation of chilli peppers are called "picante". Other "spicy" (as from spice) flavors, such as mustard, we wouldn't call them picante although in English some people might say it's spicy. We would say they are "especiado" (literally means spicy, tastes like spices) but not picante.

I believe picante chilli types of flavor all come from the Americas. Asian chilli are not exactly "picante", although for something so abstract as flavor it's difficult to make exact classifications.

Comment: “Asian chilli are not exactly "picante"” — I think this is wrong: the stuff that makes  chilli spicy is chemically identical.

Comment: It's very difficult for me to give an answer to this claim being a 100% sure of it being correct, but in my personal experience Asian spicy food (Chinese) gives me a different sensation than what I would call picante as I know it. It makes your tongue dance and it's hard to stand if you are not used. I suppose that the key here is that these classifications are cultural. The feeling caused by American chilli is different and "that" sensation is what we call "picante". Asians call the sensation caused by their own chilli with their own adjective. I guess it then got mixed up in translation

Comment: I need to clarify that I haven't tasted that many Asian chilli. In fact I have only tried one thing that remotely resembles such a thing and it's Sichuan chilli. Everything else fall under the category of spices and I wouldn't call them "picante"

Comment: Ah that explains it: Sichuan isn’t a chilli at all, it’s a *peppercorn*. It’s biologically unrelated to chilli and has a different flavour chemistry.

Comment: Since you seem to understand this topic well, let me ask you if there are native Asian chilli bilogically similar to American chilli and and I guess that will settle it. And if there are please recommend me some so I try. I'm in fact on the way to China again and I want to taste them

Comment: No, that’s the crux of the question: Asian chillies are all descendants from the plants from the Americas. In that sense, there are no “native” Asian chillies at all (or rather, those that we now call native to Asia arrived there at most 500 years ago).

Comment: The word _piquant_ does exist in English too.

Comment: The "Asian chilis are not" part may describe an observed *preference* in food. But try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhut_jolokia , made in India. And regret that I dared you to do so… The breeders have certainly left the sensible territory, for my tastes.

Comment: Curious as well is the Chinese distinction between sichuan pungency (麻 ~'numbing hotness'?) and hot-spicy-piquante chili*/*pepper pungency (辣)

Comment: In my experience of Spanish as spoken in Valencia, Spain the word *picante* can be used to describe horseradish.